# Women went alive into Gan Eden

Tags: riddle

Which women went alive into Gan Eden?

Comment: Do you mean "women" (plural) or "woman" (singular)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serach Bas Asher and Basya Bas Pahro both went alive to Gan Eden (Kol Bo Siman 118)