# Why did I become queen?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I'm Ester from the Purim story. My uncle Mordechai advised me to ask here on Mi Yodeya why Hashem made me queen of Persia, as it says:

> וּמִי יוֹדֵעַ אִם לְעֵת כָּזֹאת הִגַּעַתְּ לַמַּלְכוּת

So, does anyone have an idea what Hashem is planning for me as queen?

PS: I tried [posting this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55324/why-didnt-esther-listen-to-mordechais-instructions/55335#55335) a few years ago, but it looks like it was deleted!

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Welcome, your majesty, to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: Can you confirm if you were actually the prettiest maiden in all of Shushan or were you green ugly?

Comment: Whoever you really are, you totally stole my post [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55324/why-didnt-esther-listen-to-mordechais-instructions/55335#55335).

Comment: Is this a revived PT question, or is this a dupe?

Comment: I thought Mordechai was your first cousin?

Answer (score 6):

It is customary to declare that a monarch will live forever ([I *M'lachim* 1:31](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a01.htm#31)), but it is forbidden to lie ([*Sh'mos* 23:7](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0223.htm#7)). This creates a dilemma, as most people don't live forever.

Since you are asking a question on Mi Yodeya, you are evidently still alive. If you survived this long, you a better candidate than most to live forever and become a member of that select group of [immortal women](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3980) that includes Serach bas Asher and [Bisya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5782) bas Pharaoh ([*Derech Eretz Zuta*, ch. 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33826&pgnum=9)).

Comment: And the Megillah doesn't say that she died!

Answer (score 5):

If you hadn't become queen, the Megillah couldn't have called you אסתר המלכה. Thing is, the Megillah was certainly written by Hashem long before the Purim story happened. Because if Purim is even more important than holidays from the Torah (we see this from the fact that all others will disappear when Mashiach comes ([Megilla 10b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=10b&format=text) (h/t @Fred))), and the Torah was written 974 generations before the Earth was created ([Avot D'Rabi Natan 31:3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%90)), all the more so the Megillah was written long before Creation. And if the Megillah would be falsified by you not being queen, cha"v the Torah would also be, as we see that the Megillah which prescribes Purim (which is eternal) might be more important than the Book which prescribes the (temporary) holidays.